# How to avoid a captain america fighting style with this shield?

Tags: magic, fight

In my story I gave a character a magical captain america shield. Now that I'm writing the second chapter and am right at a combat scene, I've noticed that the fight styles is pretty much captain america. block bullets, smash with shield and then punch their face. Repeat as needed. Not terribly exciting, so I'm trying to find a different option.

What abilities (besides indestructibility) should I give the shield to avoid a captain america fighting style?

Feel free to go wild with this, it's magic so I don't really care how you would have to explain what happens. It just can't be to OP* and needs to be in the shield somehow.

If you want to read what I've wrote on it so far, scroll to the bottom of [this page](https://www.fictionpress.com/s/3352033/1/The-Second-Worlds-War) and read the last paragraph.

*shouldn't be able to destroy armored vehicles or 3+ people at once

Comment: What is the worldbuilding problem here? I read a "I need help with a plot device" question, with no metric to evaluate a best answer

Comment: quick suggestion: 1. a hidden blade within the shield preferably at the bottom. 2. a smart shield that automatically blocks the bullet (It hovers) so the captain has free hands during combat. 3. it can morph and can become a body armor to enhance a specific body part temporarily. 4. can work as a distraction at times and can return to captain at will.

Comment: Vine quote time! "We shot im the ze legs because his shield is the size of a dinner plate and his an idiot. ".

Comment: See Rising of the Shield Hero for some other ideas. Also has an MC which uses a magic shield.

Comment: Uh, a shield doesn't make you invincible. Captain America only has movie/comic book rules at his side. The fighting style doesn't *really* work IRL. Even if we assume the shield can cover the entire person that's still a cover from one side and makes him completely invincible to attacks from that side...just have two people shoot him from two sides. Or more than two. And you really just need to shoot him - close combat isn't very effective against *guns*. Unless, of course, you just want it to.

Comment: I've got to admit the question is too broad, but a lot of fun. Spiked buckler with built-in gun and force-field generator? Claymore (violates lethality clause, but...)? Use a pair, and have built-in thrusters like Iron Man (movement + weapon)? The only real justification for a shield I've seen on this web site was for a precognitive who could know where the attacks were coming from in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Why fight like Captain America?**

Looking at modern fighting styles, shields aren't often used. If they are used, there certainly isn’t any martial arts implemented.

The reason is simple. Throw your shield and you don't have it. Bullets are faster than thrown shields *[citation needed]*. The shield is only used for defence. In addition to the shield are your buddies, who can use it as a mobile cover if it's big enough. The person with the shield will generally have a firearm to complement it's shield. The reason is simple. A gun is simply too powerful compared to most other weapons. Martial arts requires you to close the distance, which is a huge disadvantage.

So what you want is a shield to protect you against bullets and a gun to fire back. If they do get too close (why would you let them?) they can still be taken out martial style, but in general you just don't want to throw away your shield or use it as your only strategy to get close. It is simply too dangerous with all the things they can do to you with guns, grenades and sheer numbers.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer the question: How does the Shield block bullets?**

As another commentator pointed out, giving someone an indestructible shield isn't going to stop someone from shooting their feet, or give them the reflexes to intercept bullets. This may seem like a non-answer, but defining this ability will also give your character more options in combat.

**Example: It blocks bullets by attracting objects that get near it.**

Now what if he's into hand to hand combat. Does it attract their wrist? What about enemies' guns, helmets, or belts?

**Example: It projects a wall of force in front of him**

What happens when someone hits this wall of force? What if he threw shards of glass into the force, would it rocket off into the enemies? If he turns the shield upside down and stands on it, what happens? Does he float?

Comment: On the wall of force example. There was a character who did that. I'll try to avoid spoilers and keep it vague. Well, the character could block projectiles or just somebody swinging a weapon. However, fire did completely bypass the shield really effectively (from the POV of the character's enemies).

Comment: "Shooting the feet" isnt exactly easy.

Comment: @Demigan not exactly hard, either. Covering your torso doesn't make you invincible. If it was, then the Roman testudo would be invincible. While it was widely successful, I wouldn't call it undefeatable. And they used rather large shields. Have a lot of people shoot at the feet of a single person and the chance they all miss gets smaller and smaller with each bullet. Even if one hits, that should be enough. You can also throw explosive at the feet or do all sort of other attacks. A shaped shrapnel charge should be able to hit. That's all assuming attacks from the shield side.

Comment: @Demigan, I assumed from the question the shield was about as big as captain America's, so the legs would be exposed too. Intentionally hitting the legs may be difficult, but accidentally getting them in a spray-and-pray from an automatic weapon, seems more likely, especially if the hero needs to close the gap to land a punch.

Comment: @Hink now that I think about it more, if the shield is bigger, for example as [a Roman shield](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Testudo_formation.jpg/1920px-Testudo_formation.jpg) or even a modern riot shield, then you get better coverage but it becomes really unwieldy for fighting with. As in, actually hitting people with the shield itself. It's also going to be a problem to punch people while holding it. Also, really easy to just throw some gas around - the shield can't stop it. Tear gas or something that's just irritating (chop a bunch of onions).

Answer (score 2):

1: it can bounce bullets. Then use it as a discount Jedi.

2: it can store a portion of the energy from impacts for a limited amount of time. Manipulation of the shield through technomagic (say extremely specific sound oscillations into the shield) can then release this energy in various ways like directional shockwaves.

3: add a weapon. Gun Fu such as the type John Wick has revived would be easy to do and add more plausibility to surviving fights due to the shield, but the protagonist would not rely solely on the shield and getting in melee for survival. You could also try more exotic weapons like a whip.

4: add other gadgets. Currently you've talked yourself into a corner as you've given your character only his shield to rely on and you build everything around it (I havent read your story but I'm going off of your question). You should let the situation determine what the protagonist has available and his shield is just one more of his tools. From using a crane, car, electrical knowledge, a pair of lockpicks or whatever you can advance the story and not have to rely on the shield and melee continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Captain America is fundamentally a generic physically superior human. His schtick is the shield, as soon as you give a generic physically superior human a shield he's going to fight like Captain America.

To break this cycle the simplest thing you could give him is a lethal weapon and the willingness to use it. Most superheroes might as well be in the WWE for all the real damage they do to their foes.

The trouble with killing your villians is of course that you need a steady supply of new ones, better to lock them up for a couple of weeks and re-use, so no lethal weapons and a touch of the moral high ground. Take your pick. Deadpool or Captain America. Sword and shield gives you something different, Wonder Woman.

Which raises a new problem, it's all been done. It doesn't actually matter that it's been done, all stories have already been done and everything is a variant. What matters is how well *you* do it.